# Mock responses are working but verification fails

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use Moq to mock an HTTP response in a unit test. I've set up my mock like below:

```
var mockHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

mockHandler
    .Protected()
    // Sets up mock for the protected SendAsync method
    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    // Prepare the expected response of the mocked HTTP call
    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Content = new StringContent("{\"stuff\":[\""+expectedstuff+"\"]}"), })
    .Verifiable();
```

I then create the httpclient:

```
var client = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(expectedRequestUri),
};
```

I then post to the client:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("/path", new StringContent(""));
```

When I deserialize the response, it matches the mocked response I set up in the Setup step above exactly, and everything appears fine. However, in the last step I encounter an issue which throws an exception (below)...

```
mockHandler
    .Protected()
    .Verify(
        "SendAsync",
        Times.Exactly(1),
        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(request => request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.RequestUri == new Uri(expectedRequestUri)),
        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
```

Error:

> Moq.MockException: Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: `mock => mock.SendAsync(It.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(request => request.Method == HttpMethod.Post && request.RequestUri == new Uri(.expectedRequestUri)), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())`

I have no clue why it's reporting 0 times, as the response I get matches the mocked response so it appears to be functioning. Any thoughts from the community would be helpful.

Comment: check the expression used in the verify. It apparently does not match what was invoked.

Comment: If the base is `expectedRequestUri` but the Post is done with `/path` then the request url would be a combining of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In situations like this you have to check the expression used in the `Verify`.

It apparently does not match what was invoked.

If the base address of the client is `expectedRequestUri`

```
var client = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(expectedRequestUri), //<--
};
```

and the Post is done with `/path`

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("/path", new StringContent("")); //<--
```

then the request url would be a combining of the two.

But in the verify you check

```
request.RequestUri == new Uri(expectedRequestUri)
```